# PHP Youshido GraphQL issue with nested fields

Tags: php-7, graphql

I am using version v1.4.2.18. The library can be found here: https://github.com/Youshido/GraphQL

I am trying to accomplish the following:

```
query { 
   articleSummary(id:1) {
       title,
       body,
       article {
          id
       }
   }
}
```

I have an ArticleSummaryField.php:

```
class ArticleSummaryField extends AbstractField
{
    public function build(FieldConfig $config)
    {
        $config->addArgument('id', new NonNullType(new StringType()));
    }

    public function getType()
    {

        return new ArticleSummaryType();
    }

    public function resolve($value, array $args, ResolveInfo $info)
    {
        return [
            'title' => 'test title',
            'body' => 'test body',
            'article' => $args['id']
        ];
    }
}
```

Then the ArticleSummaryType.php:

```
class ArticleSummaryType extends AbstractObjectType
{
    public function build($config)
    {
        $config
            ->addField('title', new StringType());
            ->addField('body', new StringType());
            ->addField('article', new ArticleField());
    }
}
```

Then the ArticleField.php has the getType method return the ArticleType which has the `id` field.

However what i am getting is an error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method ArticleField::getNullableType() in .../vendor/youshido/graphql/src/Execution/Processor.php on line 135
```

What seems to be happening is that when `$targetField->getType()` on line 135 in src/Execution/Processor.php is called its returning the `ArticleField` class, not the `ArticleType` class.

I would expect that to return the class as declared in the 'getType' method on the ArticleField class.

Am i going about this wrong for nesting fields? Or is there a bug in the library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish this you only pass the Field class as the first argument.

```
class ArticleSummaryType extends AbstractObjectType
{
    public function build($config)
    {
        $config
            ->addField('title', new StringType());
            ->addField('body', new StringType());
            ->addField(new ArticleField());
    }
}
```

Then in the field class you can override `getName` to set the name for the field as needed or it will use the class name as the field name.